# Password strength meter is not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, register

i want translate data-msg-required

I used data-msg-required="..." like this in register.phtml

```
<div class="field password required">
        <label for="password" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>"
                   class="input-text"
                   data-password-min-length="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                   data-password-min-character-sets="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                   data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                   data-msg-required="Dies ist ein Pflichtfeld."
                   autocomplete="off">
            <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
                <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
                    <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

It work, but Password strength meter not work. If i delete it, Password strength meter work, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Should the required in data-validate be in quotes?

```
data-validate='{"required":true}' data-msg-required="whatever"
```